# ReactJS: how to pass props to styling?

Tags: html, reactjs, z-index

I have the following div:

```
<div className='box-default expand' style={{zIndex: props.zindex}}>
```

When I check the element the result is:

```
<div zindex="0">...</div>
```

And it doesn't work. Shouldn't it be:

```
<div style="z-index: 0">...</div>
```

?

This is the parent container:

```
const [zIndex, setZIndexes] = React.useState([0, 1, 2]);

function setZIndex(id) {
    setZIndexes([0, 0, 0]);
    zIndex[id] = 3;
    console.log(zIndex);
}

<div
    zindex={zIndex[0]}
    onClick={()=>setZIndex(0)}
    >
```

Comment: `style={{zIndex: props.zindex}}` should work. `zindex={zIndex[0]}` wouldn't

Answer (score 1):

Passing Props down the component chain:

But your parent component should return like, and not return a div

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  ...more code

  return (
    <ChildComponent zindex={zIndex[0]} />
  )
}
```

and ChildComponent function should contain:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => (
  <div className='box-default expand' style={{zIndex: props.zindex}} >...</div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
const ParentComponent = ({ message }) => {
  const ChildComponent = zindex={zIndex[0]}

  const ChildComponent = (props) => (
  <div className='box-default expand' style={{zIndex: props.zindex}} > 
   {message}</div>
   )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that your parent component should not return a div.

```
const MyParent = () => {
  //doSomething()

  return (
    <MyChild zindex={zIndex[0]} />
  )
}
```

Child Component should look like:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => (
  <div className='box-default expand' style={{zIndex: props.zindex}} >Lorem Ipsum</div>
)
```